# VIM Syntastic error for HTML5

Tags: html, vim, syntastic

I'm a newcomer to VIM and installed GVIM successfully on my Windows 8.1 laptop. I uploaded the Syntastics plugin using Pathogen and, as I'm planning to write an ionic project, I also copied the tidy5 for html5 binary (from http://www.htacg.org/tidy-html5/) and referred to the binary in my VIMRC as follows:

```
    " SYNTASTIC
    set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
    set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
    set statusline+=%*
    " automatically load errors in the location list:
    let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
    let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
    " check on errors when a file is loaded:
    let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
    " check on errors when saving the file:
    let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
    let g:syntastic_html_tidy_execute = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\tidy-5.1.25-win32\bin\tidy'
    let g:syntastic_shell='C:\Windows\System32\cmd'
    " check debugging messages in vim with :mes:
    let g:syntastic_debug = 1
    let g:syntastic_mode_map = {"mode": "active",
      \"active_filetypes" : ["html","javascript","json"], 
      \"passive_filetypes" : ["html", "javascript","json"] }
```

When I run

```
:SyntasticInfo
```

I get the following output

```
Syntastic version: 3.7.0-76 (Vim 704, Windows)
Info for filetype: html
Global mode: active
Filetype html is active
The current file will be checked automatically
Available checkers: -
Currently enabled checkers: -
```

For some reason, my default checkers aren't loading, and when I run

```
echo syntastic#util#system('echo %PATH%')
```

I get a E484 error

```
Error detected while processing function syntastic#util#system:
line    9:
E484: Can't open file C:\Users\Dirk\AppData\Local\Temp\VIo8366.tmp
-1
```

I suspect there are multiple issues here, so I assume the first one I need to solve is the E484 error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: (1) Leave alone `g:syntastic_shell`. (2) Read `man syntastic-shellslash` and act accordingly.  (3) There is no such thing as `g:syntastic_html_tidy_execute` (it should be fine to just delete that).  (4) Your `g:syntastic_mode_map` doesn't make sense, you should specify a filetype in either `active_filetypes` or `passive_filetypes`, not both.  (5) Use the [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues) for reporting problems, not SO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that gives me something to work with.